# Why does FastCGI not work well with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, frameworks, fastcgi

It is said that FastCGI doesn't work well with Ruby on Rails deployment.  Why is that?  In previous experience, something either works quite well or it might be fundamentally wrong.  So if FastCGI is a viable solution, why is it not reliable with RoR?

Does FastCGI work well with most any language / frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [DHH himself](http://www.loudthinking.com/posts/30-myth-1-rails-is-hard-to-deploy):

> Heck, in the early days, you could
>   even run Rails as CGI, if you didn't
>   have a whole lot of load. We used to
>   do that for development mode as the
>   entire stack would reload between each
>   request.
>
> We then moved on to FCGI. That's
>   actually still a viable platform. We
>   ran for years on FCGI. But the
>   platform really hadn't seen active
>   development for a very long time and
>   while things worked, they did seem a
>   bit creaky, and there was too much
>   gotcha-voodoo that you had to get down
>   to run it well.